# How to make a split left-right text on two lines?

Tags: html, css

Need to center this text in this way:
[image]

Basically, the top part to the left and the bottom part to the right, but with a bit of overlap.

How can I do that in HTML/CSS?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what isnt working as expected? shouldnt be to hard for you nto solve it on your own with simple use of `text-align` and 2 elements or the use of `margin-left;`

Answer (score 1):

You can center the text vertically by using the centering with transform technique. Then the text should be separated into two lines and aligned to left/right plus a small negative margin so it overflows outside of the circle.

```css
div {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  display: block;
}

span:first-of-type {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -7px;
}

span:last-of-type {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>La crèativitè</span>
    <span>est contagieuse</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to center vertically it would be better practise to use flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Simply use 2 elements for those 2 lines and add a `margin-left` to the second element:

```css
.logo p {
  margin: 0;
}

.logo p:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 3.5em;
}

/* for demonstration purpose only */
html {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <p>La crèativitè</p>
  <p>est contagieuse</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another entirely different (and more complicated) approach is to use flex-box.  It requires you to use containers and to know the principles of flex-box.  But once you know what you're doing, it becomes fairly simple to center things inside of other things.

If you need somewhere to practice flex-box with simple games, you can visit https://flexboxfroggy.com/.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: gray;
}

.logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: maroon;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

#p1 {
    align-self: flex-start;
}

#p2 {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <p id="p1">La crèativitè</p>
            <p id="p2"> est contagieuse</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Bonne Chance!